# Loading a config file from operation system independent place in python

Tags: python, windows, linux

under Linux I put my configs in "~/.programname". Where should I place it in windows?
What would be the recommendated way of opening the config file OS independent in python?

Thanks!
Nathan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
os.path.expanduser('~/.programname')
```

On linux this will return:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.expanduser('~/.programname')
'/home/user/.programname'
```

On windows this will return:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.expanduser('~/.programname')
'C:\\Documents and Settings\\user/.programname'
```

Which is a little ugly, so you'll probably want to do this:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.programname')
'C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\.programname'
```

EDIT:  For what it's worth, the following apps on my Windows machine create their config folders in my `Documents and Settings\user` folder:

- Android
- AgroUML
- Gimp
- IPython

EDIT 2:  Oh wow, I just noticed I put `/user/.programname` instead of `/home/user/.programname` for the linux example.  Fixed.

Comment: "Which is a little ugly[.]" Works just fine, though.

Answer (score 14):

On Windows, you store it in `os.environ['APPDATA']`. On Linux, however, it's now recommended to store config files in `os.environ['XDG_CONFIG_HOME']`, which defaults to `~/.config`. So, for example, building on JAB's example:

```
if 'APPDATA' in os.environ:
    confighome = os.environ['APPDATA']
elif 'XDG_CONFIG_HOME' in os.environ:
    confighome = os.environ['XDG_CONFIG_HOME']
else:
    confighome = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], '.config')
configpath = os.path.join(confighome, 'programname')
```

The XDG base directory standard was created so that configuration could all be kept in one place without cluttering your home directory with dotfiles. Most new Linux apps support it.

Comment: This is a truly cross-platform answer!

Answer (score 9):

Some improvements over [LeadStorm's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3250952/624066):

Code can be simpler using `os.environ.get()` and short-circuiting `or`:

```
configpath = os.path.join(
    os.environ.get('APPDATA') or
    os.environ.get('XDG_CONFIG_HOME') or
    os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], '.config'),
    "programname"
)
```

Additionally, if you're willing to use the external libraries, [`xdg` package](https://pypi.org/project/pyxdg) can make things even easier on Linux and Mac:

```
import xdg.BaseDirectory as xdg
configpath = os.path.join(os.environ.get('APPDATA') or xdg.xdg_config_home,
                          "programname")
```

But this only solves part of your problem: you still need to *create* that directory if it does not exists, right?

On Windows, you're on your own. But on Linux and Mac, `xdg.save_config_path()` do `os.path.join()` for you, *and* create the directory with appropriate permissions, if needed, *and* return its path, all in a single step. Awesome!

```
if 'APPDATA' in os.environ:
    configpath = os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'], "programname")
    os.makedirs(configpath, exist_ok=True)
else:
    configpath = xdg.save_config_path("programname")
```

Comment: The ``os.makedirs(configpath, exist_ok=True)`` just works under py3.
py2: ``if not os.path.exists(configpath): os.makedirs(configpath)``

Comment: @greeeeeeen: For Py2, I'd recommend a `try/except` block around `os.makedirs` to avoid a race condition, in true pythonic [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) spirit

Comment: I think this is no EAFP case... if talking about pythonicity, I think, the if construction is following the "explicit is better then implicit" guide.

Comment: @greeeeeeen: testing if dir exists and _then_ creating it is [LBYL pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl) and can lead to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) if the directory is created after the `if` and before `os.makedirs()`. Very unlikely, but it's good practice to avoid racy patterns whenever we can. And, in this case, [EAFP is also faster](https://codecalamity.com/is-it-easier-to-ask-forgiveness-in-python/#sometimes-one-is-always-faster). As for "explicitness", IMHO directly trying to create and handling any errors is even more explicit

Comment: Good point. So best would be to adapt the os.makedirs implementation from python 3 in that case. There they use a try-except block as you suggested. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c717c73fa33a2f3591442059eaf6e7a673e2c725/Lib/os.py#L196

Answer (score 2):

My approach when using Python's Pathlib library:

```
config = environ.get('APPDATA') or environ.get('XDG_CONFIG_HOME')
config = Path(config) if config else Path.home() / ".config"
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, configuration and data files for programs on Windows go in the %APPDATA% directory (or are supposed to), usually in a subdirectory with the name of the program. "%APPDATA%", of course, is just an environment variable that maps to the current user's Application Data folder. I don't know if it exists on Linux (though I assume it doesn't), so to do it across platforms (Windows/Linux/MacOS)...

```
import os

if 'APPDATA' in os.environ.keys():
   envar = 'APPDATA'
else:
   envar = 'HOME'

configpath = os.path.join(os.environ[envar], '.programname')
```