# Cross-platform method to obtain the user's configuration home directory in Python?

Tags: python, cross-platform, configuration-files

My program needs to store some configuration files. The major operating systems seems to have a designated location to place those; for instance, on Freedesktop.org compliant systems, it will be the path stored in the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment variable.

Is there a method (or a library) to obtain this configuration home directory across the major operating systems: Windows, OS X, Linux?

Comment: Your question is stated better but you can find better answers here : [Loading a config file from operation system independent place in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250164/loading-a-config-file-from-operation-system-independent-place-in-python/3250952#3250952)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading a config file from operation system independent place in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250164/loading-a-config-file-from-operation-system-independent-place-in-python)

Comment: As of now, the best answer to this question is there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63699709/3926735; though the next ones are good ones too.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the package [`appdirs`](https://github.com/ActiveState/appdirs). This is developed by ActiveState who must have quite a lot of experience on cross-platform python.

```
import appdirs
appdirs.user_config_dir(appname='MyApp')
```

The package is just a single file (/module), so if you need it for a small script it is simple to just copy what you need. Otherwise the package is available with both `pip` and `conda`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

print os.path.expanduser("~/.my_config/data")
```

will always allow you to write  ... config files are best stored *where **you** want them*

oftentimes on windows this is

```
os.path.expandvars("%appdata%/.my_config")
```

most other systems tend to put the in the userprofile director (~)

unless you are looking for a specific configuration file location(perhaps to interact with another software... in which case we would need to know which software)

Comment: The issue is that `~/.my_config` is not the standard location for configuration files. This implies several downsides. For instance, if I'm the user, even a power user, I won't be able to locate / properly reset / back-up that configuration. I'm trying to obtain the proper, standard path to place configuration, and yes, in some versions of windows that will be %appdata%, and OS X probably uses yet another location, but the point of the question is to get whatever location it is, across all major platforms, with (ideally) one function call.

Comment: how is that not the standard? many professional softwares place it there...  (thats the first place I would look for config files in a linux system) ... hell thats where you put your os config files (.bashrc, etc) ) ... most powerusers would look in the home directory imho ... if you want users to manually edit these files than you should document that they are in the users home directory ...

Comment: While some config files, e.g. "dot-files", are directly under the home directory, that is not a standard place. Check out the [Freedesktop specs](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), which many software packages do follow. Moreover, it's certainly not standard across platforms, for example on Windows.